# Can someone be held responsible for an immoral action they have no memory of?

Tags: ethics

Suppose someone commits an immoral action. They permanently lose their memories afterwards. Can they still be held responsible for the action?

Comment: Yes.  Why should they not be?

Comment: So if I commit mass murder in another country by let’s say by chemical weapons intentionally designed to kill people right then and there you will clear me of all charges?  I mean I designed and planned to kill 2 million and succeeded killing 2 million and I some how get amnesia before I get captured and brought to justice that I should get away with the immoral act?

Comment: @Logikal Because the person that did the killing is not the same person that you are now. So you kinda have to argue your way around some "ship of theseus" problem in terms of are you the same person or aren't you. And if you aren't is it just to punish you for something you didn't do?

Comment: @haxor, in the hypothetical above I am the same person doing everything. I am not the master mind only & other people do the dirty work. I see you are trying to go with the you are not the same person from your past now type defense. That is pure emotional & Psychology. It will not work in a court of law 8 out of 10 times with tough juries. Almost all will convict me based on the facts. The OP is saying if I somehow don't recall any of my actions I should just be set free.  Morality doesn't work that way. There is no subjectivity in morality! People confuse authority for what is right & wrong.

Comment: @haxor789 why do you believe that you're not the same person if you lose your memory? I don't remember what I did a day ago. Guess I can steal your belongings and get away with it since my memory is garbage and I'd forget about the incident /s

Comment: @Logikal What juries and judges do is based on, not arbitrary, but made up rules. So that's not "objective" at all. I mean you yourself argue with fractions like 8/10. And no I can very much question the morality of your perception of morality, that is not at all objective either. Also what do you want to achieve with the punishment? Usually answer to that are a) safeguarding the population b) revenge and c) rehabilitation. So if a) the person is not a) threat and c) rehabilitation isn't necessary. So you could argue that you accomplish nothing with that, but actually make it worse.

Comment: @ActualCry I mean thing about it what it mean from the perspective of the person that has lost their memory. Like what it means if you're charged with a crime that you don't know anything about, that you don't conceive yourself capable of and that you strongly think you haven't done and would never do. Not to mention that memory loss likely has a reason (biologically, chemically, traumatic, etc), so it might actually be that you've altered something so that you're no longer the same person. Also you might be inculpable but still end up institutionalized just not as punishment.

Comment: @haxor789, you are confusing thing again. You need to grasp concepts in philosophy correctly. I never stated court are objective or authority is objective. As a matter of fact it is the opposite. Science is not objective either no science leads to certainty in knowledge. You are confusing terminology. I gave a hypothetical which could serve as a counter example to the OP.  If anyone uses fractions or probabilities then they can't be objective-- that is a sign the knowledge is NOT objective. You don't seem to understand objective as a concept. It cannot change value ever.

Comment: @Logikal That raises the level as to what is considered "objective" to ridiculously high levels where you need a "supernatural" for an example, because pretty much everything natural is subject to constant change. So gods or ideas? We can suspect certainty and underlying patterns but as we can't prove them we can't confirm that they are there. And while you can have certainty in pure reason, you can't confirm that you're abstract fantasy world is a correct model of reality and applies to it, so how useful is that? So why should morality be absolute and objective?

Comment: @haxor789, You can't deny objective knowledge. Your claim " . . . Pretty much everything natural is subject to constant change" is objective if that claim is never false! Which lane do you want to stay in? Either your above claim is sometimes false or it is always true. So you too can make an objective claim & can not deny objective knowledge. Awareness is not required for knowledge to be objective. The question "how do you know . . . " is a scientific question not philosophy. Because you can't prove x means nothing. That is not a thing. Because I can't prove x doesn't make x false by default.

Comment: @Logikal Sure you can make the argument that it either is or isn't true, regardless of whether I am aware of it. But if it's true nature isn't revealed to me, how could I know and if I CAN'T know how could I know that it even is a binary? I mean I don't have a concept for it not being binary but that doesn't mean that none exist. Or what about hyperdimensions that appear changing to me but are in fact static from a different point of view? What are they then and which point of view matters?

Comment: @haxor789, There is only one context as far as objective knowledge goes not many different meanings. Truth values must be binary necessarily. Awareness doesn't make claim x true or false. You seemed to agree with that. The more specific details we have we get to find out the truth value. It may take years or centuries to find out. Because I don't know if Jupiter has life doesn't change the truth value whatsoever. "There is a Christian  God" must be either true or false. Because there is no evidence, no proof or that we are unaware doesn't change truth value of a proposition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137100/discussion-between-haxor789-and-logikal).

Answer (score 2):

All that matters is whether the act was deliberate at the time it was implemented. This is what it means to be held accountable for something then and there.

If later the memory of it is lost is irrelevant (as long as the previous statement is true).

Suppose now that one really did not commit such an act and is falsely accused of it. Then the burden of proof is on the accusers which they cannot really bare. Thus no actual problem is posed.

Suppose now that one has a false memory of commiting such an act (eg through an electroshock, intoxication or other manipulation). There is no act that was implemented, thus the (false) memory of it is again irrelevant.

A more realistic example: someone commited a deliberate crime and is now dead (the memories are lost with the person). Isn't the (now deceased) person (historically) accountable for it then and there?

Locke held that someone who has no memory of an event is *defacto* a different person (assuming of course amnesia is genuine and not faked). Still, isn't the same person *historically* accountable for an action the person has already committed? In other words, isn't the action an established historical fact, committed by a real person? The current person is the *unique historical successor* of that person,  the heir of the same rights and responsibilities. Suppose a person that is *defacto* different but without amnesia, instead, by radically and genuinely changing his mind. Is the person still accountable? So some person took away the money of the poor and kept it in a safe, this person is now a *defacto* different person (one way or another), should the person return the money?

Some references on this matter:

1. [Memory, Identity and Responsibility](https://iai.tv/articles/should-people-be-punished-for-crimes-they-cant-remember-committing-what-john-locke-would-say-about-vernon-madison-auid-1050)

Disclaimer: whether someone is accountable is a different issue from supporting the death penalty.

Comment: I was thinking of History also. It doesn't matter if the person is alive or dead, remembers or not, a particular thing did happen, influenced by particular people, not all of whom may have been charged, and some people or influence might still be active now. The only point in looking at the past is to prevent problems in the present and future.

Comment: I mean a dead person is dead, unless time travel is a thing there is no way to hold them accountable. That's a thing for the living not the dead, so you can hold a mock trial to discuss the case, but nothing you do or don't do will have an effect on the deceased. In term of the money in the safe, well that's also obvious. He should give it back. Either he isn't the same person, then he has no claim on it, or he is then he has no claim on it either. The changed person though is interesting, also what about juridical persons like states, companies, collectives of all kind.

Comment: @haxor789, but which person do we charge with returning the money? Implicitly we assume historical accountability. That is the point

Comment: @NikosM. Well the money historically belonged to the person that it was stolen from (for the sake of argument assuming that this case is binary guilty/innocent, which might not be the case for real disputes) and regardless of whether you're dealing with the thief or a person occupying the same body as the thief, that money is to be returned. That's independent of the question whom you charge. Though likely they lost money by not having the money and those loses would either be taken by the no-longer thief or the victim and neither is ideal.

Comment: @haxor789, then the demon that occupied the body should be more careful, it is accountable now for the money. :)